# Question- find the number of possible integer solutions for the equation $(1+a+b)^2 =3(1+a^2+b^2)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**

> Find the number of possible integer solutions for the equation
>   $$(1+a+b)^2 =3(1+a^2+b^2)$$

I tried finding ordered pairs by finding $b$ in terms of $a$ but I find no way to reach the point where the relation between $a$ and $b$ is clear enough to answer the question.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's integer solutions.thanks for pointing that out:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try solving for $b$ in terms of $a$:

$$(1+a+b)^2=3(1+a^2+b^2)$$

$$1+2a+2b+2ab+a^2+b^2=3+3a^2+3b^2$$

$$2a^2+2b^2-2a-2b-2ab+2=0$$

$$a^2+b^2-a-b-ab+1=0$$

$$b^2-(a+1)b+a^2-a+1=0$$

$$b=\frac{a+1\pm\sqrt{(a+1)^2-4(a^2-a+1)}}{2}$$

$$b=\frac{a+1\pm\sqrt{3(-a^2+2a-1)}}{2}$$

For there to be non-complex solutions we need $-a^2+2a-1\ge0$. But: $-a^2+2a-1=-(a-1)^2$ so the only solution is $a=1$ and hence $b=1$.

Comment: Wow!I never thought about using discriminants to solve the question. Thanks for the solution! :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=(1,1,1)$ and $y=(1,a,b)$. Then, by Cauchy-Schwarz:

$(1+a+b)^2=<x,y>^2 \le ||x||^2*||y||^2=3*(1+a^2+b^2)$

Since $(1+a+b)^2 =3(1+a^2+b^2)$, we have "=" in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, therefore $x$ and $y$ are linear dependent. It follows that

$$a=b=1.$$

Comment: Thanks for that solution :). Hopefully one day I would have learnt enough to understand it completely but till then I am limited by my knowledge.thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Set $S=a+b$ and $P=ab$. Then, recalling that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$, your equation can be written
$$
1+2S+S^2=3+3S^2-6P
$$
or
$$
P=\frac{S^2-S+1}{3}
$$
The values of $S$ and $P$ are not arbitrary: the limitation is that $S^2\ge 4P$, so we get
$$
\frac{4}{3}(S^2-S+1)\le S^2
$$

> This turns out to simplify as $(S-2)^2\le 0$.

Can you finish up?

Comment: That is a very elegant and awesome way to solve it! Thanks for that cool new approach!